# In FastAPI / Pydantic how can I define a return dictionary class that returns a dictionary of tuples

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastAPI request that returns a JSON like this

```
{
  "1": [
    [
      "HH",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "DD",
      "0"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Basically, it's a dictionary with tickets numbers as a key (here "1") and a list of tuples (two strings each).

Is there a way to turn this structure into a Pydantic model so that I can use this with FastAPI as a response model?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by defining a [custom **root** type](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types)  and using a [conlist](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#arguments-to-conlist), up to Pydantic V1:

```py
from typing import Dict, List

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist

app = FastAPI()


class ResponseModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, List[conlist(item_type=str, min_items=2, max_items=2)]]


@app.get("/result", response_model=ResponseModel)
async def get_result():
    a = {"1": [["DD", "0"], ["HH", "0"]]}
    return ResponseModel.parse_obj(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Pydantic V2 would have `conlist(item_type=str, min_length=2, max_length=2)`.
[Current docs on `conlist`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conlist).

Comment: For me, this is not working. `{'1': [['DD', '0]), ['HH', '0']]}` causes the error pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ResponseModel
response -> __root__ -> 1
  unhashable type: 'list' (type=type_error) and turning the inner lists into tuples give me the error: pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for ResponseModel
response -> __root__ -> 1 -> 0
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
response -> __root__ -> 1 -> 1
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)